# Треугольник Паскаля. Помогите разораться, почему программа выдаёт ошибку? ( Задача решена, нужно просто вывести без нулей )

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
n = int(input())
matrix = [[0 for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
for i in range(n):
    matrix[i][i] = 1
for i in range(n):
    matrix[i][0] = 1
for i in range(2,n):
    for j in range(1,i):
        matrix[i][j] = matrix[i - 1][j] + matrix[i - 1][j - 1]
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if matrix[i][j] < 1:# место  ошибки. и matrix[i][j] == 0 не работает одна и та же ошибка inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation. Остальная часть работает.
            print('      ')
        elif matrix[i][j] < 10:
            print('    ', matrix[i][j], end='')
        elif matrix[i][j] < 100:
            print('   ', matrix[i][j], end='')
        elif matrix[i][j] < 1000:
            print('  ', matrix[i][j], end='')
        elif matrix[i][j] < 10000:
            print(' ', matrix[i][j], end='')
        elif matrix[i][j] < 100000:
            print('', matrix[i][j], end='')
        else:
            print( matrix[i][j] % 1000000, end='')
    print('')
```

Comment: а где у вас там нули?

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input())
matrix = [[0 for i in range(n+1)] for j in range(n+1)]
for i in range(n+1):
    matrix[i][i] = 1
    matrix[i][0] = 1
for i in range(2,n+1):
    for j in range(1,i):
        matrix[i][j] = matrix[i - 1][j] + matrix[i - 1][j - 1]
for i in range(n+1):
    for j in range(i+1):
        print('', matrix[i][j], end='')
    print('')

7
 1
 1 1
 1 2 1
 1 3 3 1
 1 4 6 4 1
 1 5 10 10 5 1
 1 6 15 20 15 6 1
 1 7 21 35 35 21 7 1
```

С выравниванием столбцов по максимальной длине чисел

```
mx = 1
for i in range(2,n+1):
    for j in range(1,i):
        matrix[i][j] = matrix[i - 1][j] + matrix[i - 1][j - 1]
        mx =max(matrix[i][j], mx)
l = len(str(mx))+1
for i in range(n+1):
    for j in range(i+1):
        print(f'{matrix[i][j]}'.rjust(l, ' '), end='')
    print('')

9
   1
   1   1
   1   2   1
   1   3   3   1
   1   4   6   4   1
   1   5  10  10   5   1
   1   6  15  20  15   6   1
   1   7  21  35  35  21   7   1
   1   8  28  56  70  56  28   8   1
   1   9  36  84 126 126  84  36   9   1
```

Comment: а почему для 7 получается 8 строк?

Comment: Потому что считает до C(7,k)

Comment: А, понял, я тупанул. Не додумался до того, чтобы просто выводить треугольник, а не смотерть,  входит ли это число матрицы в треугольник.      Спасибо

Comment: ОК. Не забывайте про https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer